# design to visible the fields in salesforce

Tags: profile

I have 2 profile A& B, in lead I have 10 fields, among that only 5 should be visible to A and rest five should only be visible to B, How you will design it

Comment: you can use different  pagelayout for both users or just go to profile and change the field level security..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using custom fields, you can also set the field level security by clicking on the field you want to hide from the profile and then click the button "Set field level security" on top of the page. If you want to hide standard fields, then you will need to assign different page layouts to different profiles as shown in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Question : by "lead" do you mean LEAD SObject?
If yes, then you can do this by giving different PAGE LAYOUTS to different profiles.

[Assigning Page Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutassign.htm)

[Assign Page Layouts in the Original Profile User Interface](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_orig_page_layouts.htm&language=en_US)

Hope it helps!!